# Why does click package validation fail?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I'm trying to publish an app for Ubuntu touch, but I can't get past the validation phase.
I'm using Ubuntu SDK. The current build configuration is for device (armhf). I was able to run the app on the device. From the "Publish" tab, I clicked "Build and validate click package", and I got 11 "Error" nodes, with no further information.
[image]

The same if I select "Validate existing click package" and choose my click file from the build directory.

I did expand the "Log" node, but there's just a huge JSON with nothing suspect inside (not that I understand much of its content).

How could I find out what's wrong?

---

Edit: On a closer look, I found this error in the [log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12018607/):

```
"error": {
  "security_policy_version_matches_framework (Trolly.apparmor)": {
    "manual_review": false,
    "text": "Invalid framework 'ubuntu-sdk-15.04-html'"
  }
}
```

My `apparmor` file contains:

```
{
    "policy_groups": [
        "networking",
        "webview"
    ],
    "policy_version": 1.3
}
```

Comment: I can't read the text in your very tiny screenshot, can you please post a full size image of the window? However, it also sounds like this is a bug in the SDK which needs to be reported. You should obviously not have useless error messages. You should be able to check the "Compile Output" or "General" tabs at the bottom of the SDK screen though, to see what the tool output to the command line.

Comment: @dobey, I added the full-size screenshot. Also, in the "Compile Output" there was [this text](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12018607/) (seems to be the same as the one under the "Log" node). Found one possible error related to `security_policy_version_matches_framework` (added in the question).

Comment: Are you creating an HTML5 app, or an app which simply uses networking and the web view?

Comment: It's a QML app which only needs read-write access to disk. The two permissions were there by default, and I don't know why it complains about the "-html" framework (I chose the generic one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an outdated version of Ubuntu SDK.
When I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04, the SDK ppa was disabled, and I didn't receive further upgrades.

After enabling the PPA again, I had to do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`:

```
Unpacking qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu (3.1.1+15.10.20150720-0ubuntu1~0vivid1) over (3.1.1+15.04.20150421-0ubuntu1~0utopic1) ...
```

Now the validation works.